# Getting 'code not found' error in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry-simulator

I am working on a Blackberry project. My project was working fine before I added a new class, but when I add that class and try to run the application, it is giving me the Uncaught Runtime exception, `ApplicationEntryPoint`, `ApplicationMangerException`. I extract the main code file and there are 11 code files get generated, 10 are of size between 61 to 68 Kb and the 11th code file is of size 10 kb. I'm also getting the error in console saying Module "TestProject-11" not found. Does anyone have an idea what may be wrong?

Comment: *"Getting cod not found error in blackberry."* Have you tried haddock? *(Sorry, bad joke...)*

Comment: I've fixed some of the spelling errors and typos. Can you post the **full** text of the actual exception? Along with the name of the class you added and the name of your main application class.

Comment: Here I am posting the error that i am getting and also the exception that i am getting.
//////////////////////////
Console error :

Starting TempCamApp
Searching installed codfiles for alias 'TempCamApp-11'
Searching uninstalled codfiles for alias 'TempCamApp-11'
Module 'TempCamApp-11' not found.Error starting TempCamApp: Module 'TempCamApp-11' not found.
//////////////////////////
Exceptions:

java.lang.RuntimeException
net.rim.device.api.System.ApplicationManagerException
net.rim.device.apps.api.ribbon.ApplicationEnterPoint

Comment: You can use the "edit" link just under the question to update the question. When you do, note the **How to Format** box to the right of the question text box, and also note [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area. Those will show you how to format the exception so people can read it.